# Sencha touch form panel is not showing

Tags: sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2, sencha-architect

For some reason my form panel isn't showing. Can anyone help?  I'm a newbie so sorry if this is obvious! It was build with Sencha Architect but I can't understand why no fields are showing in the form?...

```
Ext.define('MyApp.view.Login', {
    extend: 'Ext.Container',

    config: {
        layout: {
            type: 'vbox'
        },
        items: [
            {
                xtype: 'titlebar',
                docked: 'top',
                title: 'My Title'
            },
            {
                xtype: 'toolbar',
                docked: 'top',
                items: [

                    {
                        xtype: 'button',
                        text: 'Call'
                    },
                    {
                        xtype: 'button',
                        text: 'Email'
                    }                       
                ]
            },
            {
                xtype: 'container',
                flex: 1,
                border: 2,
                items: [
                    {
                        xtype: 'formpanel',
                        styleHtmlContent: true,
                        items: [
                            {
                                xtype: 'fieldset',
                                title: 'MyFieldSet',
                                items: [
                                    {
                                        xtype: 'textfield',
                                        label: 'Field'
                                    },
                                    {
                                        xtype: 'textfield',
                                        label: 'Field'
                                    }
                                ]
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    }

});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change the `layout` of your Login view from `vbox` to `fit`. Then set the `layout` of the container that contains your formpanel to `fit` also.

Check [this link](http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2-0/#!/guide/layouts) for more info about layouts in Sencha Touch.

Comment: 'of the containers' which ones ?

Comment: Both containers;) I've edited the answer for more clarity. Thanks.

Comment: It actually only need a layout: 'fit' on the container containing the formpanel

Comment: Yes, you're right. I was checking it in Architect for myself and I forgot to set the `flex` property on the container containing the formpanel when the Login view has a `vbox` layout. If the `flex` property is not set, then both containers should have `layout: 'fit'`.

Comment: Actually, since I marked this correct why doesn't flex: 1 have the same effect as fit if there is nothing else inside the container?

Answer (score 4):

To display formpanel (Ext.form.Panel) using Sencha Touch 2.3+ correctly inside other container you need to add `scrollable: null` property

```
{
    xtype: 'formpanel',
    scrollable: null,         
    items: [
        ...
    ]
}
```

See discussion [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9459732/sencha-touch-2-formpanel-not-showing-up-properly-layout-issue)